# Finding a function that connects 3 points on a graph in the shortest path.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, interpolation

I have $3$ points on a $2$d graph. Say, $(X_1, Y_1)$, $(X_2, Y_2)$, $(X_3, Y_3)$. I want to find a function which is sum of several modulus functions which can achieve this  .

For example,

1. $(-1,1)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$.
   The function connecting these points in shortest path is $|x|$ or modulus of $x$.
2. $(0,2)$, $(1,4)$, $(1.25,5)$.
   The function connecting these three points in shortest path is
   $$
   |x| + |x-1| + |2x+1|. 
   $$

> Find the series sum of modulus function that joins $(X_1, Y_1)$, $(X_2, Y_2)$, $(X_3, Y_3)$.

Comment: So say $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$, then the shortest path (that is a function) will be the 2 straight lines that connect these three points. Hint:  How can we find a sum of 2 modulus that does this?   EG $|2x-1|+|2x+1|$ works for the second example.

Comment: I graphed |2x-1| +|2x+1| and found that it  does not work for the second example, it takes a longer path compared to the |x| + |x-1| + |2x+1|

Comment: Sir, your path distance for the three points.     i.e., (0,2), (1,4), (1.25,5) is 3.59 .My function gives a path distance of 3.26

Comment: Oh, I see the error that I made when trying to combine from your solution. I found a sum of 2 modulus hat went through those 3 points, but it didn't give me those 2 line segments so it isn't the shortest distance.  $\quad$ So, correcting my example,  $|3x+1| + |x-1|$ works for the second example. It agrees with your path on $[0, 1.25]$.

Comment: I had not thought of that sum. one thing I had notice from your solution and mine is that the coordinate (1,4) that is between the other two points has to remain a critical point, while the other two coordinates don't really need to.

Comment: Right, so focus on "how do you take a piecewise function consisting of 2 straight lines connected at a point, and turn that into a sum/difference of 2 modulus?" (Note that this answer is unique) $\quad$ To get my answer, I wasn't testing out different possibilities, but was doing that procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hint: We have a piecewise function defined by 2 line segments. Then, there exists a (unique) way to express this as the sum or difference of 2 modulus expressions. This gives us the desired result.

Further Hint: $\max (a, b) = \frac{ |a+b| + |a-b| } { 2}$.
Find a similar formula for $ \min (a, b)$.

Comment: @Anonymous To check, you fully understand what is going on here? I'm slightly surprised at how quickly you accepted the answer.

Comment: Sir, yes I have understood and have solved the question successfully and derived a general formula as well.